# Ansible get the value of a variable inside of variable

Tags: ansible

Trying to solve this issue somehow :

deploy.yml:

```
- vars:
    site_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'MY_SITE') }}"
  hosts: "{{ site_name }}"
  roles:
    - { role: deploy, tags: ["release"] }
```

having group_vars file :

```
mysite1:
  - name: 'mysite1'
    docroot: '/var/www/mysite1.com'
    codebase: ''
    db_host: '192.168.1.100'
    db_user: 'myuser'
    db_pass: 'mypass'
    db_name: 'mydb'
```

and the playbook task file:

```
---

- debug: "msg='Host site name {{ item.name }} db_host {{ item.db_host }}'"
  with_items: site_name
```

And running the playbook with:

```
export MY_SITE=mysite1 ; ansible-playbook -i myinventory deploy.yml -e @group_vars/sites.yml
```

However this is not right, getting :

```
fatal: [myhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'unicode object' has no attribute 'name'"}
```

Of course the variable "site_name" contains the value "mysite1" and I would like to get from group vars the value of mysite1 ...
Can anybody point me to the right direction? (far as I read in the docs the variable in variable or evaluate a variable is not yet possible...)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to try host_vars? 
As a example:

# tree

```
├── deploy-playbook.yml
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   ├── mysite1.yml
│   └── mysite2.yml
└── roles
    └── deploy
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

# cat hosts

```
[sites]
mysite1
mysite2
```

# cat deploy-playbook.yml

```
---
- vars:
    site_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'MY_SITE') }}"
  hosts: "{{ site_name }}"
  roles:
    - { role: deploy }
```

# cat host_vars/mysite1.yml

```
---
name: 'mysite1'
db_name: 'mydb1'
test:
  name: 'test_mysite1'
  db_name: 'test_mydb1'
```

# cat host_vars/mysite2.yml

```
---
name: 'mysite2'
db_name: 'mydb2'
test:
  name: 'test_mysite2'
  db_name: 'test_mydb2'
```

# cat roles/deploy/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- debug: msg='{{ name }} - {{ test['name'] }} - {{ db_name }} -  {{ test['db_name'] }}'
```

And results:

# export MY_SITE=mysite1 ; ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy-playbook.yml

```
PLAY [mysite1] *****************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [mysite1]

TASK [deploy : debug] **********************************************************
ok: [mysite1] => {
"msg": "mysite1 - test_mysite1 - mydb1 -  test_mydb1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
mysite1                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

# export MY_SITE=mysite2 ; ansible-playbook -i hosts deploy-playbook.yml

```
PLAY [mysite2] *****************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [mysite2]

TASK [deploy : debug] **********************************************************
ok: [mysite2] => {
"msg": "mysite2 - test_mysite2 - mydb2 -  test_mydb2"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
mysite2                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```